# How to wirte a left join query in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

can some one tell me how to write this mysql query in codeigniter??

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4)
                 ON (t2.a=t1.a AND t3.b=t1.b AND t4.c=t1.c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->select(*);
$this->db->from('t1');
$this->db->join('t2','t2.a = t1.a','left');
$this->db->join('t3','t3.b = t1.b','left');
$this->db->join('t4','t4.c = t1.c','left');
```

Alternatively (condensed)

`$this->db->select(*)->from('t1')->join('t2','t2.a = t1.a','left')->join('t3','t3.b = t1.b','left')->join('t4','t4.c = t1.c','left');`

Reference: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: thank you for your help. can you also tell me how to add second argument to a join statment? 
like
$this->db->joing('t3','t3.b = t1.b' and 't3.b != 1','left');
is there a way to do like this?

Comment: ok ok i found a way
$this->db->where('Working_today !=', 0) this works for me after your query. 
thanks again Mr.laiello